# Search the record with multiple condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form with Multiple input. I am trying to search the record based on the value given in form field (some field may be empty)Kindly help me to achieve this.This forms takes me to other form and display the record. Whenever value of any field is  blank or not selected it does not give any output [image: Search Form]

```
$facility=$_POST[facility];
$user=$_POST[user];
$type=$_POST[type];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfacility join tbluser on tbluser.id=tblfacility.user where facility = '".$facility."' AND type= '".$type."' " ;
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I have taken only three variable in this form now it will be all field

Comment: You can use `OR` operator instead of  `AND` because  `AND` will match with other values as well where else `OR` will match for each value. `SELECT * FROM tblfacility join tbluser on tbluser.id=tblfacility.user where facility = '".$facility."' OR type= '".$type." OR somecondition_here...`

Comment: Your not using prepared statements correctly. You must parameterize all variables.

Comment: @danish-khan-I If i use OR operator the it will not work for multiple condition

Comment: It should be `$_POST["type"]`

Comment: @dev what  do you mean multiple conditions? you can wrap your condition in parenthesis. `SELECT * FROM tblfacility join tbluser on tbluser.id=tblfacility.user where facility = some_condition AND type = type OR (column = column AND column = column) AND (column = column OR column = column)`. <- that's an example how you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by dynamic where depends on the input.
Here first store all input data into an array, named as $input_data and rest condition can be applied in the loop. so this'll check for all inputs.

```
$input_data = $_POST;

$where = " where 1=1";

foreach ($input_data as $key => $value) {
    if($value && !empty($value)) {
        $where .= "AND $key = '$value'";
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblfacility join tbluser on tbluser.id=tblfacility.user $where" ;
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Can u explain it bit because i m new to this